# Notification when table view row is deselected during multiselection IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a table view with multiselection enabled. I want to call a webservice when the table row is selected and a different webservice when it is deselected. I have noticed that on table view selection the didSelectRowAtindexPath is called but its not called on deselection. Is there any way to trigger an event when a row in table view is deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the UITableViewDelegate methods [tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW19) and [tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW10).

Comment: I have used this but it doesn't get fired. I have checked the documentation and its given :These methods will not call the delegate methods (-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:), nor will it send out a notification.

Comment: [Here's a video of an example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/475192/15732052.mov) that triggers `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` whenever a cell is deselected. Are you saying yours isn't behaving this way? Can you post code from your UITableViewDelegate, or a screencapture video?

Comment: Thanks. I had a subview of table view controller after setting the delegate and datasource it worked.I don't have enough points so cannot vote.  :)